# Trying to average a list of numbers using functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

First and foremost, I am new to python. As of such, I only know for loops, range, lens, and sum to do this problem. I am having difficulty trying to make a function that can average list of numbers.

This is my code so far:

```
def ave(L):
    L = list(range(len(L))
    for a in range(len(L)):
        if len(L) == 0: return 0
        else: return float((sum(L))/len(L))
```

So far, I am getting a syntax error on my third line with `range(L)`.

Comment: You replaced `L` with a range on the first line of the function; doesn't matter what the rest of the function does from there on out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is return the sum of `L` divided by the length of `L`:

```
def ave(L):
    if not L:
        return 0
    return sum(L) / len(L)
```

No `range()` or `float()` or `for` required.

In Python 3, `/` always produces a floating point number. `sum()` will do all the looping for you. The only thing you need to take care of, is returning `0` if the list is empty.

Comment: It can also be `return sum(L)/len(L) if L else 0`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: yup, but I tried to keep it to syntax the OP already tried to use.

Comment: One question In Python < 3, `float((sum(L))/len(L))` is wrong it should be `float(sum(L))/len(L)`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: these days I always use `from __future__ import division` instead and not worry about when to use `float()` at all.

Comment: Many thanks for all of the help, however, I am still getting a [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str']

When inputting a list.

Comment: that means that your list contain strings

Comment: @Yozuru: Then your input list contains strings. Make sure you don't mix types, the function in my answer assumes that all values in the list are numbers.

Comment: @Matijn: Again, I appreciate the help Marijn. I tried typing something like : ave(['1','2']) and I still get the error, I'm wondering if I am doing something drastically wrong.

Comment: `ave(['1', '2'])` passes a list of strings; `ave([1,2])` passes a list of ints.

Comment: @Yozuru: You are giving it a list of strings, not numbers. Remove the quotes, or use `[int(n) for n in L]` to turn all values in the list into integers first.

Comment: @Martijn: Ooh I see now! Many thanks, I'm still fairly new to python and this has been a great help!

Answer (score 1):

Following line is missing a `)`:

```
L = list(range(len(L)))
                      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Because average of empty list is undefined, you should rather return None instead of '0'.
And instead checking for length, it is better to catch potential error, according to [EAFP principle](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp). It makes also more clear what are you doing, as error is self-descriptive.

```
def ave(L):
    try:
        return sum(L) / len(L)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return None
```

Comment: hmmm Nice.. I will this approach.